# Using Electron and Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, electron

I'm using Vue.js and Electron. It's working great and I can pass all my data to the mainRenderer with `webContents.send(...)`.

The problem is, that my App has different pages. Actually, they are loaded with `webContents.loadURL(...)`, when the user click a link in the renderer process:

```
this.window.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/html/index.html`)

...

ipcMain.on("login", (event: any, message: any) => {
    // getting the user from the message ...
    ...

    this.window.webContents.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/html/loggedin.html`)

    this.window.webContents.once("dom-ready", () => {
        this.window.webContents.send("user", user)
    })
})
```

This works, but there is one problem: Vue can only do his magic work, when the DOM is loaded. So sometimes there is a small flickering, because the data on the page cannot be changed as fast as Electron shows the already loaded DOM (Vue has to be loaded at the end of DOM).

So what is the best practice to do this? I thought about using Express and a template system, but running a webserver in Electron isn't feeling right.

Comment: I've been using [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) which (among other things) lets you use Vue's normal router within Electron.

Comment: Isn't the idea of using a framework like vue.js to stay on the same page? Vue.js provides it's own routing system, which handles all the dom replacements locally and all you need to do is loading the index.html once and handle everything by changing your content/components based on your routes. I'm not familiar with electron, but is there no way loading an url like index.html#/login ?